# Toolbar TextInputLayout EditText - lost HINT

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

please I have a problem with my second toolbar.

I want to have a TextInputLayout in my toolbar, but I do not want it to be FOCUSABLE. It will be used for filters. So user can not type to that editText.

My code:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:minHeight="@dimen/spacing_xxlarge">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lNameLayout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                        android:paddingStart="30dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="30dp"
                        android:paddingRight="30dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/ldesc"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"

                            android:clickable="false"
                            android:cursorVisible="false"

                            android:focusable="false"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:text="another toolbar text"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlack"
                            android:hint="@string/pref_title_filters"/>
                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

When I use:
                                android:focusable="false"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="false", my HINT disappear.

What should I do? Thanks !! :)

[image]

Comment: why do you want second textbox as edittext, You can change it to textbox .

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can do the following:

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(null);
yourEditText.setText("Whatever you want");
```